# How assign a function which returns muliple values to a variable (python)

Tags: python, function, variables

NORMAL CODE:

```
s = list(range(1))

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

RESULT: (Vertical Display)

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I want the same result using a function which i can assign to a variable and use inside a string literal.

```
def results():
    for i in s:
        print(i)

numbers = results()
report = f"Here is the list on numbers: {numbers}"
```

RESULT: None

When i use 'return' inside function, i get just one value.

Any better way to do this???

Comment: Read about Python generator functions.

Comment: Did you mean: `print(s)`?

Comment: Generators functions are what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, a generator won't do what you want, since you'll need to call your function in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The function needs to collect all the results into a list instead of printing them. You can use a list comprehension for this.

```
def results():
    return [i for i in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you return within a function in python in a for loop, it will return the singular value and cease function execution. In this particular case, this should work if your desire is only string formatting:

```
def results():
    ret = "\n"
    for i in s:
        ret += str(i) + "\n"
    return ret

s = [1,2,3,4]

numbers = results()
print(f"Here you go: {numbers}")
```

Comment: This would be better is `s` was a parameter of `results()`.

Comment: @quamrana I was just trying to match the structure of his existing code

Comment: Ok, I see. I normally like to make another small improvement in my answers. But also: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Answer (score 0):

```
def results():
    s = list(range(10))
    for i in s:
        print(i)
    return s

numbers = results()
report = f"Here is the list on numbers: {numbers}"
```